# Adding new Scope to Google OAuth Consent Screen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

We have an existing app that uses the [Google Cloud OAuth Consent](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent) screen, we currently have one scope for Google Search Console.

The 'Google Search Console API' is not a sensitive scope, and we are published live with it with lots of active users.

Now we are adding an optional feature that requires GA4 access, so we want to add 'Google Analytics API', which is a sensitive scope

We know we need to add the scope to the Auth Consent Screen, but we don't want to interrupt the experience of our users who won't be using the new feature needing the additional scope.

I believe if we add the new scope, and enter all the required information about usage etc, existing users will be seeing an 'unverified' screen until we get verified.

All of the examples seem to be creating an App and defining all the scopes before; I've not found anything about adding a new scope and gracefully requesting access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the new scope the users using the current scope will not be effected. You will need to apply for verification again for the new scope.  Anyone who uses any part of your app that uses the new scope that has not yet been verified is going to see the not verified auth screen warning.

Just dont release the code to production that will use the new scope and no one should notice.

Comment: How about new users who sign up but don't use the new scope?

Comment: They should be fine.  The team has assured me that its only if you request that new scope that the users will see the unverified app screen.  If you continue to use the scope you have verified you shouldn't see it.